# Hybrid encryption tools besides openssl and gnupg?

Tags: encryption

I'm looking for something off-the-shelf, or relatively simple/safe to construct, which can encrypt large (>2GB) backup files with a public/private keypair, and can be configured and deployed easily for use in a simple backup script.

As such I understand I'm looking for hybrid encryption.

OpenSSL's S/MIME implementation would work in principle, except in practice it is broken for anything larger than ~1.5GB. See for example:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/2515

And I'd prefer to avoid GnuPG for use with automation in future, since in the past I've not found configuring the keyring very amenable to non-interactive deployment tools. It tends to assume there's a person typing at a terminal.

Some use of one of the various NaCl bindings might also do the job, but this also exposes a bit more of the gory details than I'd prefer.

To test feasibility I've written a hybrid encryption tool which uses openssl commands from a Bash script:

https://github.com/wu-lee/hencrypt

However I would much prefer something which, besides fitting my requirements above, is a) not written in Bash, b) peer-reviewed by experts, which I am not.

*Edit:* Target OS - Linux (specifically latest Ubuntu LTS).  Suitable software would be open source.

Comment: Hi! Did you see the comment about using openssl's `-stream` option in the issue you linked?

Comment: Also, check out [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/)! Apparently, with gpg, you [can also use asymmetric keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-duplicity-with-gpg-to-securely-automate-backups-on-ubuntu).

Comment: @ambiso - yes to -stream, but it doesn't work when decrypting.  Which means you can encrypt a big file, but then discover you cannot decrypt it!  See my comments in the README file of my hencrypt project.

Comment: @ambiso - and yes, indeed I have been using duplicity, but I've encountered an obstacle course of bugs and issues with uploading to S3 which made me give up on it.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question again and include some details on the OS it should run on, and your price margin in case of paid software? Thanks!